# Restart scapy from a Python script

Tags: python, ipv4, scapy

Hi is there any method so i can restart scapy while the script is still running?

I change an interface MAC address and i need to restart Scapy in order to see the changes.

Thanks!

Comment: what invocation misses the change in your MAC address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Helmut for your interest. I managed to solve the problem by making a .bat file with commands from here:  [Change MAC from cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19237962/2399087) and then call .bat file from python.

Initialy i was trying to use Popen to execute commands from script but no modifications to registry were made.